# Why functions not called during runtime?

Tags: c, function, runtime-error

I am new to C. I want to design a simple data manager. in the main function, I call the login function and it works fine. Then, I print a statement and call the choosetask function. The cmd waits for me to input the tasknumber. Then the program ends without calling the next functions.

```
int main()
{
  login ();
  printf ("choose a task to perform (write its number to go):\n 1- Insert the data of a new patient.\n 2- Assign a patient to a hospital.\n 3- Load a hospital patients data.\n 4- Delete a patient data.\n 5- Exit.\n\n");
  choosetask ();
  return 0;
}
```

```
void choosetask ()
{
    int tasknumber;

    scanf ("%d", tasknumber);

    if (tasknumber == 1)
    {
    newpatient ();
    }

    else if (tasknumber == 2)
    {
    assignpatient ();
    }

    else if (tasknumber == 3)
    {
    loadhospitaldata ();
    }

    else if (tasknumber == 4)
    {
    deletepatient ();
    }

    else if (tasknumber == 5)
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    else
    {
      printf ("Choose a valid task number, please\n");
      choosetask ();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should compile with warnings (in GCC and clang, for example, it's "-Wall"). This hints such mistakes.

Comment: Thanks. I really don't know how I didn't notice that.

Comment: What do you mean by compiling by warnings? I work on code blocks and use gcc.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `gcc` in command line mode (here with Linux) with following source code:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int tasknumber;
    scanf ("%d", tasknumber);
    return 0;
}
```

you get:

```
$ gcc -Wall test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:6:5: attention : format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf ("%d", tasknumber);
     ^
test.c:6:11: attention : ‘tasknumber’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     scanf ("%d", tasknumber);
           ^
```

If you fix your source code:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int tasknumber;
    scanf ("%d", &tasknumber);
    return 0;
}
```

you get no more warnings:

```
$ gcc -Wall test.c
$
```

Note: this is just an example to get a first level of warnings. You can also use other gcc options like`-pedantic` to get more warnings or `-std=c11` to check with respect to C11 standard.